# Surface Fitting Python

Tags: curve-fitting, surface

I'm trying to fit a set of data (x,y,z) to obtained a best fit of the resulting surface through curve_fit. In particular z array has to be NxM "matrix". To show you an example I'll share you the code I wrote:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

#Generate random 3D data points
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = np.sin(X * Y)


def func(xy, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    x, y = xy
    return a + b*x + c*y + d*x**2 + e*y**2 + f*x*y




#Perform curve fitting
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (X, Y), z)

#Print optimized parameters
print(popt)
```

When I launch the code I get the following error

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\..\PycharmProjects\GSP_Speed\prova.py", line 21, in <module>
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (X, Y), z)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\..\PycharmProjects\GSP_Speed\venv\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py", line 963, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\..\PycharmProjects\GSP_Speed\venv\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py", line 428, in leastsq
    retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.`
```

Can someone help me to get sort out the problem?
Thank you very much

I tried to use both x,y and X,Y as inputs in the `curve_fit` function but it doesn't work

I tried already to use both x,y and X,Y as inputs for `curve_fit` but didn't work

Comment: No actually I'm trying to fit some random [x,y,z] data without any function relationship

Comment: I've a series of data [x,y,z] collected from two sensors, and I need to find a function that links z with x and y through a best fit of the resulting surface z(x,y)

Comment: I didn't give you because it's a huge array and didn't want to complicate things... Anyway the function I want to use for the fitting is the one defined in func, that will have to fit the z(x,y) data

Comment: I see. I had my wires crossed and confused the objective with the sample data. Still, linking data would allow us to give better advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function `curve_fit` expects an array-like training input. The result for provided `(x,y)`-dataset is `[-0.04166698  0.13532234  0.12139508 -0.0873608  -0.07659318  0.83186632]`. Check it out your self!

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

# Generate random 3D data points
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(X * Y)

def func(xy, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    x, y = xy
    return a + b * x + c * y + d * x**2 + e * y**2 + f * x * y

# Flatten X and Y arrays
X_flat = X.flatten()
Y_flat = Y.flatten()

# Perform curve fitting
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (X_flat, Y_flat), z.flatten())

# Print optimized parameters
print(popt)
```

Comment: [All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: Bro, the answer is correct AND I performed the usual answer review. What else did you expect? Nonsense...

Comment: If I hide my means and show results, will you thumbs up the answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot I found the solution based on your answer, I had put some effort to adjust the array shape but at the end the baseline is that

Comment: I am glad, you found the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to generate random data for the x and y axes - you can just make them regular for test purposes.

`sin` will be difficult to fit, even as an example. Instead consider writing `p0` (which you need to do anyway), passing it to `func` and adding noise to the result.

You should be passing in a Jacobian (and testing it via `check_grad`) to `curve_fit`; I haven't shown this.

Don't pass in the result of `meshgrid` to `curve_fit` directly. Instead, after `meshgrid`, you need to reshape to (2, -1).

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np


def generate_data(
    rand: np.random.Generator,
    p0: tuple[float, ...],
    n: int = 10,
) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # x
    np.ndarray,  # y
    np.ndarray,  # z
]:
    x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=n)[np.newaxis, :]
    y = x.T
    z_ideal = func((x, y), *p0)
    noise = rand.normal(scale=0.1, size=z_ideal.shape)
    z = z_ideal + noise
    return x, y, z


def func(
    xy: np.ndarray,
    a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float, e: float, f: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    x, y = xy
    return a + b*x + c*y + d*x**2 + e*y**2 + f*x*y


def fit(
    x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, z: np.ndarray,
    p0: tuple[float, ...],
) -> tuple[float, ...]:
    xy = np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y)).reshape((2, -1))
    popt, _ = curve_fit(
        f=func,
        xdata=xy, ydata=z.ravel(),
        p0=p0,
    )
    return popt


def main() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    p0 = (0, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    x, y, z = generate_data(rand, p0)
    popt = fit(x, y, z, p0)
    print(popt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```